# running an excel macro that compares selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro on selected cells - where the macro compares a cell to it's neighbor beneath him - changes their color and moves on to the next pair of cells.

it's A 1 dimension array where I want to compare each pair of cells (1st with the 2nd, 3rd with the 4th etc.)

I tried working with

```
For Each cell In Selection
```

but then I don't know how to compare the given cell to the one beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample code.

```
Sub compare()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Selection  '

    For Each cell In rng
        'makes comparison
        'offset(1,0) is used to find one cell below active cell
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0) Then
            cell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Updated answer

```
Sub compare()

    Dim rows As Long
    rows = Selection.rows.Count - 1

    Dim selCol As Long
    selCol = ActiveCell.Column

    Dim selRow As Long
    selRow = ActiveCell.Row

    For i = selRow To (selRow + rows)
       If Cells(i, selCol) = Cells(i, selCol + 1) Then
            Range(Cells(i, selCol), Cells(i, selCol + 1)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, but this compares every cell with the one beneath it. i wanted to check 2 pairs at a time and then move to the next pair.
I added a condition to suit my need but if you can explain how to do so it might help other people.

Comment: my code is a pairwise comparison. you may want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub compareCells()
    Dim i As Integer
    'Check dimension
    If Selection.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "not 1d array"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Check size
    If Selection.Rows.Count Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "size not even"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For i = 1 To Selection.Count / 2
        With Selection
        If .Cells(2 * i - 1) = .Cells(2 * i) Then
            'what you want to do here, for e.g. , change color
            .Cells(2 * i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            'what you want to do here
            'MsgBox "neq"
        End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```